# Was Rabbi Matya ben Harash the son of a deaf-mute or is "ben Harash" just a coincidence?

Tags: mishna, tannaim

Talking about the rabbi who appears in Mishna Yoma 8:6, Pirkei Avot 4:15.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: charash is also carpenter

Comment: ........lumberjack

Comment: He was blind at one point : מעשה בר' מתיא בן חרש שהיה יושב בית המדרש ועוסק בתורה, והיה זיו פניו דומה לחמה וקלסתר פניו דומה למלאכי השרת, שמימיו לא נשא עיניו לאשה בעולם.
פעם אחד עבר שטן ונתקנא בו, אמר: אפשר אדם כמו זה לא חטא?!
אמר לפני הקב"ה: רבש"ע, רבי מתיא בן חרש מה הוא לפניך?
א"ל: צדיק גמור הוא.
אמר לפניו: תן לי רשות ואסיתנו.
א"ל: אין את יכול לו, אף על פי כן!
א"ל: לך.
נדמה לו כאשה יפה שלא הייתה כדמותה מעולם, מימות נעמה אחות תובל קין, שטעו בה מלאכי השרת, שנאמר: ויראו בני האלהים את בנות האדם. עמד לפניו, כיון שראה אותו הפך פניו ונתן לאחריו.
שוב בא ועמד לו על צד שמאלו, הפך פניו לצד ימין,

Comment: ימין, היה מתהפך לו מכל צד.
אמר: מתירא אני שמא יתגבר עלי יצר הרע ויחטיאני.
מה עשה אותו צדיק?
קרא לאותו תלמיד שהיה משרת לפניו.
א"ל: לך והבא לי אש ומסמר.
הביא לו מסמרין ונתנום בעיניו, כיון שראה השטן כך, נזדעזע ונפל לאחוריו.
באותה שעה קרא הקב"ה לרפאל, א"ל: לך לרפא את ר' מתיא בן חרש.
בא ועמד לפניו.
אמר לו: מי אתה?
אמר לו: אני הוא רפאל ששלחני הקב"ה לרפאות את עיניך.
אמר לו: הניחני, מה שהיה היה.
חזר לפני הקב"ה אמר לפניו: ריבונו של עולם, כך וכך אמר לי מתיא.
אמר לו: לך ואמור לו: אני ערב שלא ישלוט בו יצר הרע.
מיד רפא אותו.

Comment: Yalkut Shimoni 161 Breishis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deaf person is called a חֵרֵשׁ (*cheresh*), i.e. with a tzeire, not *charash* (with a patach) or *chorosh* (with a komotz).

While nikkud is a relatively modern addition to the texts of Mishnayos and Gemara, generally the tanna Rabbi Matya is called בן חָרָשׁ, (*ben charash/chorosh*, depending on your havhara), i.e. with komotzim.

A חָרָשׁ generally means an engraver or another type of artisan. Compare [Shmuel 2 5:11](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.5.11?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וַיִּשְׁלַח חִירָם מֶלֶךְ צֹר מַלְאָכִים אֶל דָּוִד וַעֲצֵי אֲרָזִים **וְחָרָשֵׁי** עֵץ **וְחָרָשֵׁי** אֶבֶן קִיר וַיִּבְנוּ בַיִת לְדָוִד

The word וְחָרָשֵׁי above is חָרָשׁ in plural construct (smichut) form, and in the pasuk here clearly means artisans of wood (i.e. carpenters) and of stone (i.e. stonemasons).

So, assuming that the way we pronounce the name of this tanna is correct, Rabbi Matya ben Charash should mean Rabbi Matya son of an artisan (such as a carpenter or stonemason), not of a deaf man.

Comment: There's also חֹרֵשׁ a plower. But this all just begs the question how the editors decided how the name should be pronounced?

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed. However, I assume this is down to our mesorah. The same would go for many of the more obscure words in Shas whose meaning is dependent on the pronunciation.

Comment: It's possible there are rishonim (perhaps the Aruch?) who'd comment about the meaning of names and who had what profession

Comment: Professions and physical signs are commonבן הקצב, בן החורני, בן קריאת,